# Pattern to use with multiple web service calls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

this is a general architecture question. I have an .aspx page with around 10 user controls, and each of them is issueing a web service call to render its contents. At the moment the web calls are made synchronously, so the overall page rendering time is quite slow (>2 sec).

I am thinking of using asynchronous calls to render the controls, to reduce the page loading time. Could you point me to some resources on how to do that, preferably with the newer TPL library? (I don't want to use Async CTP yet). I know how to use the Task library to create asynchronous calls, I'm just not sure how the whole scenario would work having multiple user controls, each requiring asynchronous web service loading but all user control tasks should finish before the page is rendered.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks
Themos

Answer (score 0):

You probably need asynchronous calls from each  control, but there is also the possibility of making the entire page load asynchronous:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

making the page async does not make your service calls happen in parallel though, and this is probably what you need. For this you need asynchronous calls within each control.

Hope it is of some use.

Comment: Interesting, it does not explain the use of RegisterAsyncTask from a user control context though. Do the same rules apply?

Also, the article is dated back in 2005. Doesn't the TPL library provide any similar but cleaner implementation?

Comment: No doubt TPL provides usefull wrappers around the Threadpool and async calls. The problem which neither async pages nor TPL targets is that page event happens sequentially and that you will have to bind data for all controls in init or page load and not advance to render until the binding has completed. I would make the webservice calls outside the controls and invoke them using Tasks, wait for all to complete and then bind when all data was loaded. This may heavily impact your existing work though.